# Implementations of count_until and accumulate_until?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, c++11, stl

Given an input sequence, the standard algorithms `std::count` and `std::accumulate` count the number of occurances of a specific value (or predicate matches for `std::count_if`) and the accumulation of a given associative operation (sum, product, Boolean or/and, min/max, string concatenation, etc.), respectively.

What if one wants to know whether an input sequence contains exactly/at least/at most `n` occurances/matches, or accumulates to a sum of exactly/at least/at most `n`? The brute-force way would be to compare the result of `std::count` or `std::accumulate` against the target `n`, but that would miss out on an **early exit** opportunity when the count or accumulation exceeds the target already halfway through the input sequence.

One could e.g. make a `count_until` as

```
template<class InputIt, class T, class Pred>
auto count_until(InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value, Pred pred)
{
    auto res = 0;
    for (; first != last; ++first)
        if (*first == value && pred(++res))
            break; // early exit if predicate is satisfied
    return std::make_pair(first, res); // iterator and value to allow continuation    
}
```

and from which one could test for equality/at least/at most by using a suitable predicate and comparison against the returned count.

**Questions**:

- is it possible to write `count_until` (and similarly for `accumulate_until`) using a combination existing standard algorithms, possibly in combination with a suitable [**Boost.Iterator**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html)?
- In particular, I was thinking of a `find_if` over an `accumulate_iterator` where the predicate would extract the count or sum from the iterator.
- Or do `count_until` and `accumulate_until` warrant inclusion as standalone primitives in a future version of the Standard Library?

**Edit**: I think the most useful formulation is to return a `std::pair` of an iterator and the count at the point where the predicate is first satisfied. This enables users to continue iterating.

Comment: you can use an `std::map` to keep the count of the occurrences

Comment: You could already do what you want with `std::find_if` with a Predicate with state.

Comment: @Jarod42 care to formulate an answer? Preferably where the predicate is passed from the outside to `count_until`.

Comment: @TemplateRex: my version posted as answer.

Comment: By the way, the names appears to me ambiguous as the 'until' predicate may refer to Iterator or 'working result'.

Comment: @Jarod42 the `until` applies to a satisfied predicate. Every algorithm takes two iterators as an input range, and none of them has the `until` suffix, so I am not really worried about such confusion.

Comment: @TimothyShields no, "exactly `N`" and "at most `N`" can be aborted after the `N+1`-th encounter, "at least `N`" after the `N-th` one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was thinking of a combination of std::find_if with a state predicate:
(Pred is normal user predicate.)

```
template<class InputIt, class T, class Pred>
typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type
count_until(InputIt begin, InputIt end, const T& value, Pred pred)
{
    typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type count = 0;
    auto internal_pred = [&count, &value, &pred](decltype(*begin) elem) {
        return elem == value && pred(++count);
    };

    std::find_if(begin, end, internal_pred);
    return count;
}

template<class InputIt, class T, class Pred>
T accumulate_until(InputIt begin, InputIt end, T value, Pred pred)
{
    auto internal_pred = [&value, &pred] (const T& t) {
        value += t;
        return pred(value);
    };
    std::find_if(begin, end, internal_pred);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Maybe use `std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type` instead of `size_t`.

Comment: Thanks and accepted. BTW, the `accumulate_until` only works for monotonous accumulation (say addition for positive integers). If the input can be negative, then `accumulate_until` will stop as soon as the total becomes negative (e.g. in gambler's ruin problem). So I think that `accumulate_until` should return a `std::pair` of an  iterator and a value, rather than only a value, so that users can decide to continue iterating from the point of first failure. I also considered returning only an iterator from `count_until`, but it seems impossible to implement `is_count_equal_to` that way.

Comment: Both methods may return `pair<iterator, ..>` (easily). `is_count_equal_to(.., n)` may be computed as `n == count_until(.., MoreThan(n + 1))`.

Comment: That short-circuiting logic in count_until's internal predicate is a work of art.